# BB in thumb and first flight ahead

Tags: air-travel, public-transport, airports, airport-security

A few years ago I was shot in the thumb by a bb gun and the bb is still in there. You can physically see where the bb is since there is a bump and you can still see the scar about a half of a inch away. I'm not sure which type of metal it is made of I think it was copper. I'm just concerned on if they will let me fly or if it won't even be picked up. If it does will it help to have a doctors note? Or will that be no difference at all.

Comment: Why didn't you get it out?

Comment: I didn't know it was in there until about a week later. I thought my thumb was broke since there was a bump and I couldn't move my thumb but I put a magnet to it and it stuck.

Comment: sorry but I Lol'ed :D, so why didn't you remove it after you notice it? It won't be that hard to remove plus how sure are you that the metal inside your body will not cause some serious health problems in time as it disintegrates...

Comment: I wouldn't think it will be detected at all.  It seems like less metal than would be in a ring or similar piece of jewelry, and people don't normally take those off to pass through metal detectors.

Comment: BTW, you are not alone: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140319142845AAbWm8U

Comment: I had a knee surgery 5 years ago and The doctor told me I was going to have 1 or 2 screw (or nail, or something alike I don't know for sure) inside my leg for good. I've catched a lot of flights since then and never set any alarm because of it. Probably your BB won't too.

Comment: I have titanium plates in my arm after a car accident, and they've never triggered the alarms. I'm sure a BB won't be noticed. (I'd still be tempted to have the BB removed, though, but just for personal comfort/health reasons!)

Answer (score 5):

It's very unlikely to set off the metal detectors.  Think about how many people walk through wearing eyeglasses, or in the good old days, shoes (which often contain small metal pieces).

If it does set off the detector, do not panic.  Just tell them  you have this thing, they can touch your finger, and they will probably wave their metal-detector wand around your hand then let you go.

A doctor's note would be useful if none of the above works out, but most likely you'll never use it.  If you're going to spend the time and money to get such a note, better just spend a bit more and get the BB removed.

Comment: It's not that much different from a metal pin used to help set a broken bone, except much easier to verify.